# Sort NsArray using group by two values

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I am confused with sorting NsArray as am very new in iOS development, I have a custom array, I want to sort my NsArray which has the value as below as group by `callType` and `numberId`:

```
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 14:42:10 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:27";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
    },
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 14:24:19 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:15";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 9;
    },
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 13:59:18 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:11";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
    },
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 13:57:55 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:09";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
    },
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 13:56:02 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:12";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
    },
    {
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 13:55:41 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:00";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
    }

)
```

and the result should be something like  where i get the count in each group

```
   {
        count = 4 // number of 
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 14:42:10 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:27";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 8;
   },
   {
        count = 1 // number of 
        callID = 1;
        callType = 4;
        dateTime = "2013-10-11 14:24:19 +0000";
        durationOfCall = "00:00:27";
        numberCalled = 91xxxxxxxxx;
        numberId = 9;
   }
}
```

Here is my custom class for above

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RecentCallsModel : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *callID; // Integer 32
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *callType; // Integer32
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *numberId; // Either phone number or the contact id
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *dateTime; //Date and time
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *durationOfCall;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *numberCalled;


@end
```

Comment: @O'cool please make the Question clear is this array of custom objects? if so please specify..
which properties you need to combine for the sorting

Comment: @Raon Yes it's an array of custom objects

Comment: @O'cool Are you sure you don't mean NSDictionary objects?

Comment: No am sure its not NSDictionary object am using core data to extract these values which returns me NSArray,

Comment: so it is a class .. isnt? and this callerID and callType etc as properties can you just give the class definitions .h files where i can see all the properties?

Comment: ok you need callType and numberId isnt? and what is this count? i didnt understand .. now hw would you like it>>

first compare callType if both are same then numberId or some otherway?

Comment: Count would be the number of appearance of object within the group.

Comment: and the sortlogic?
how? ,is it like

first compare both CallType if they are different then sort according to them 
if they are same compare the second criteria...ie, numberId..

ie if two 
obj1{CallType=1NumberID=2}
obj2{CallType1=NumberID=9}
obj3{CallType=3NumberID=4}
obj4{CallType=3NumberID=2}

here
obj3>obj4>obj2>obj1 isnt?

Comment: The CallType and NumberID both make a group if either is different it should go in other group. This is some thing like Sqllite groupby command

Comment: last one is count also part of the new the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will work......

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) 
{
    NSNumber *firstCallType = [(RecentCallsModel*)a CallType];
    NSNumber *secondCallType = [(RecentCallsModel*)b CallType];
    NSNumber *firstNumberID = [(RecentCallsModel*)a NumberID];
    NSNumber *second NumberID = [(RecentCallsModel*)b NumberID];
    if([firstCallType compare:secondCallType]==NSOrderedSame)
               {
                if([firstNumberID compare:secondNumberID]==NSOrderedSame)
                         {
                        //count logic
                         }
               else
                   return [firstNumberID compare:secondNumberID];
               }
   else
              return [firstCallType compare:secondCallType];
}];
```

Comment: k, ill try and revert